# Wordpress: PHP redirection if a variable contains a word

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to redirect my users from a page to another depending of a variable which I obtain with a CURL request. In this example, if my user is on Page1 but the variable $result contains the word "Yes", I want him to be redirected to Page2.

My wordpress website breaks down when I upload the following code.

```
<?php
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
curl_init("https://www.mywebsite2.com/{$info}");

//set options 

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);



//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);


$start = strpos($result, 'info1 ');

$end = strpos($result, 'end', $start);

$length = $end-$start;

$result = substr($result, $start, $length);

return $result;

//**************************************************
// Redirection on my wordpress website using $result

add_action( 'wp', 'redirect' );
function redirect() {
  if ( is_page( 'page1') && (false !== stripos($result, 
'YES') ) {
  wp_redirect(get_page_by_title( 'page1'));
  exit();
  }
  else {wp_redirect(get_page_by_title( 'page2'));
  exit();
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: For now I see two errors on your code, first `<?Php` must be changed to `<?php` and `Else` must be changed to `else`

Comment: Is $result as global var?

Comment: $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function with wp_redirect().  Thus it needs ';'

```
wp_redirect(get_page_by_title('page2'));
else{wp_redirect(get_page_by_title('page1'));
```

Also wp_redirect requires an exit.   Add exit(); after each redirect.  [wp_redirect documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect' );
function redirect() {
  if ( is_page('page1') && (false !== stripos($result, 'YES') ) {
  wp_redirect(get_page_by_title( 'page2'));
  exit();
  }
  else {wp_redirect(get_page_by_title( 'page1'));
  exit();
}
}
?>
```